# Django is_authenticated() always returns false on index page, but not on other pages

Tags: python, django, authentication

I use the same layout.html on different pages on my website, which includes a login check.

```
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            Signed in as <strong>{{ user.username }}</strong>.
        {% else %}
            Not signed in.
        {% endif %}
```

If I log in, the statement returns true on all pages except my index page. I therefore suspect something is wrong with my registered urls. However, I can't find the problem.

My site/urls.py:

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import include, path
    from django.conf.urls.static import static

    urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("app.urls")),
    ]
```

My app/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name = "index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name = "login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name = "logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name = "register"),
    path("lobby/<str:lobby_name>/", views.lobby, name = "lobby")
]
```

My site/settings.py:

```
    import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '123'
 
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
 
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
 
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
 
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
 
ROOT_URLCONF = 'site.urls'
 
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
 
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'site.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'site.asgi.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1' , 6379)],
        },
    },
}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.User'
 
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
 
 
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/lobby/'
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
 
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
 
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
 
USE_I18N = True
 
USE_L10N = True
 
USE_TZ = True
 
 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

my app/views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.http import Http404
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
from django import forms
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import *


def index(request):
    return render(request, "app/index.html",{
        "user": User.username
    })


def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        user = authenticate(request, username=request.POST["username"], password=request.POST["password"])

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "app/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid username and/or password."
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "app/login.html")


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))


def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST["email"]

        # ensure password matches confirmation
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
        if password != confirmation:
            return render(request, "app/register.html", {
                "message": "Passwords must match."
            })

        # attempt to create new user
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, "app/register.html", {
                "message": "Username already taken."
            })
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        return render(request, "app/register.html")
```

If anybody knows a solution, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To check if the user is authenticated or not you don't need to pass the user object. You have overidden the default object of django. So my suggestion is that you don't pass the user object it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

```py
def index(request):
    return render(request, "app/index.html",{
        "username": request.user.username # don't overwriting user
    })
```

You seem to be passing the username to the user attribute, thus overwriting the default `user` object.

> When rendering a template RequestContext, the currently logged-in user, either a User instance or an AnonymousUser instance, is stored in the template variable {{ user }}:

-- from the django docs: [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#users)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the index method

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "app/index.html",{
        "user": User.username
    })
```

Replace it with

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "app/index.html")
```

In the template you can access your logged in user's username by {{ user.username }}. So no need to override the default object

Comment: it will be `{{ user.username }}` only without `request`. [Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#users)

Answer (score 0):

actually in html use `user.is_authenticated` ->  `request.user.is_authenticated`